# On running `yarn start` QR Code is not visible, instead I get the following

Tags: react-native

I have:

```sh
node -v: 14.0.0

npm -v: 6.14.8

yarn -v: 1.22.10
```

Steps to `yarn start`:

```sh
yarn global add create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app confusion
cd confusion
yarn start
```

I get the following:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-native start

               ######                ######
             ###     ####        ####     ###
            ##          ###    ###          ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##           ##    ##           ##
            ##         ###      ###         ##
             ##  ########################  ##
          ######    ###            ###    ######
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ##
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###
          ######    ###            ###    ######
             ##  ########################  ##
            ##         ###      ###         ##
            ##           ##    ##           ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##          ###    ###          ##
             ###     ####        ####     ###
               ######                ######

                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

Answer (score 1):

yarn start just starts dev server. to run the app you have to
`npx react-native run-android`  or `npx react-native run-ios`

refer https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup (Scroll to Running your React Native application)

Answer (score 0):

Select a template when you are creating the app by `create-react-native-app confusion`

then you would be able to avoid this stage.